# Powershell Script To Install MSI Completes Without Actually Installing MSI

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I have a script that installs an MSI. The script completes without any errors but the MSI is never installed. I can verify this in Control Panel. The MSI is supposed to generate a machine certificate and that certificate is not being created as it should so the install is not actually working.

Here is my function:

```
    function installMSI(){
        $msiArgs = '/i', "DeviceRegistrationTaskSetup.msi", 'INSTALLDIR="c:\Program Files\DeviceRegistration"', 'EXEOPTIONS="/q2 URL=https://deviceregistration.com"', '/qn'
        Write-Host "Installing $msi..."
        Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $msiArgs -Wait -NoNewWindow
}
```

If I remove the `/qn` from the script, the MSI installer pops up instead of installing with the set arguments. Is there something wrong with the Arguments I am passing to the MSI? I can't seem to understand why it would complete without errors.

Comment: Try to get more information by running the installer with logging enabled, and see if the log file gives you more information: `Start-Process msiexec.exe -Arg '/log logfile.txt /i installer.msi /qn FOO=bar...`

Comment: Is the script running with the proper credentials? Generating the certificate usually required admin credentials and this might be one of the reasons the install fails.

Comment: I was able to generate a log file which showed I was being blocked by some security policy. Not sure why since it worked before. I will continue to find that out. thanks